# Using xa transactions in Karaf

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

I'm trying to create a xa transaction between postgres (using pax-jdbc to set up xa datasource) and activemq in karaf, using blueprint and camel.

The setup is the following: I have a camel route which receives a jms message, does some database updates, and then sends a jms message to another queue. This other queue then reads the updated records.

The problem is that the second queue is reading the old data instead of getting the updated data.

I believe the cause is that JMS transaction is being "released" first, and the database has not commited the changes yet.

If I put a Thread.sleep(1000) on the second queue, I always read the correct data. Also, I believe the transaction is working fine, if I throw an exception in the camel route, I see no changes in the database, and the jms message does not get sent, proving they are working together.

Here's my blueprint with the jta configs and camel route:

```
    <blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
        http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/transaction/transactionv20.xsd">

  <tx:enable/>

  <bean id="resourceManager" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.ActiveMQResourceManager" init-method="recoverResource">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTxManager" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="resourceName" value="activemq.localhost" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="0"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="$ext{brokerUrl}"/>
    <property name="userName" value="karaf"/>
    <property name="password" value="karaf"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.JcaPooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="name" value="activemq.default"/>
    <property name="maxConnections" value="4"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTxManager"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- define the activemq Camel component so we can integrate with the AMQ broker -->
  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <!-- due to a bug in activemq-camel we must configure using a nested configuration bean -->
    <property name="configuration">
      <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsXaPoolConnectionFactory"/>
        <!-- JTA transaction manager (Spring interface to Aries-TM) -->
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="springJtaTxManager"/>
        <!-- IMPORTANT: We set local transactions to false, because the JtaTransactionManager
             will take care of enrolling the XA JMS Connection when needed. -->
        <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
        <!-- IMPORTANT: and disable cache level as the JtaTransactionManager needs to control the consumers
             from its JcaPooledConnectionFactory -->
        <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <reference id="jtaTxManager" interface="org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.RecoverableTransactionManager"/>
  <reference id="springJtaTxManager" interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager"/>

  <bean id="required" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="springJtaTxManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
  </bean>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" id="om-bstask-context" useMDCLogging="true">
    <route id="notificationConsumer">
      <from uri="activemq:queue:incomingNotification"/>
      <transacted ref="required"/>
      <doTry>
            <!-- execute some bd updates -->
            <to uri="activemq:anotherQueue"/>
        <doCatch>
          <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
          <handled>
            <constant>false</constant>
          </handled>
          <bean beanType="xxxx.MessagingUtil"
                method="logErrorMessage(${headers.JMSXDeliveryCount}, ${headers.om_txid}, 'incomingNotification', ${exception})"/>
        </doCatch>
        <doFinally>
        </doFinally>
      </doTry>
    </route>
  </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Do I have something wrong with my setup? Or what could explain this behavior?

PS I got the config from https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter12/xa-karaf/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/camel-context.xml

Comment: Is this maybe setting up two transaction managers?

Comment: @eckes beacuse of jtaTxManager and springJtaTxManager?

Comment: yes I don't know how the spring manager works but I would expect it needs to have a reference to the JTA manager to coordinate.

Comment: @eckes I think I need both because different beans of activemq expect either javax.transaction.TransactionManager or org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager. For example JmsConfiguration uses PlatformTransactionManager

Comment: Yes both, the question is how to link them

Comment: In case of karaf the two TransactionManagers should be no problem as they both are implemented by the same class in Aries transaction